# List of most popular Android phones?

Tags: android

As Android developers, we know the important of testing on physical devices--and as many as possible. Given a limited budget, it's logical that we would want to test using the most popular Android phones and tablets to help ensure our apps work for as large a percentage of the market as possible.

Is there a regularly updated resource showing the most popular phones and tablets? Preferably in the US. The information must be out there--reported sales from manufacturers, statistics from the Android Market, etc... I just don't see everything I'd like in one place.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only resource I've found so far is AppBrain: http://www.appbrain.com/stats/top-android-phones

This is a useful and frequently updated set of statistics, but I don't know that AppBrain is the most representative of device usage as a whole, so I appreciate better suggestions.

Comment: I don't think this is a good site, every time I've checked they basically list all the Samsung devices.  There's no way that Samsung always has the 20 most popular Android devices, especially when you look at the Nexus line.

Answer (score 3):

By version (API level): http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

[image]

Comment: I think sorting by API is better than actual device. You want to know what API to target, and if your applications layout was done correctly, you shouldn't have a problem. Good answer.

Comment: He asked for devices. You answered with API levels. I think that is the better approach to testing.

Comment: Ah, yes. I actually read the question so quickly I missed that distinction. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, I want DEVICES, not API levels. Even given the same screen size, API level and screen density, different devices will have different issues. So no, just getting one device per API level is NOT enough.

Comment: @Chad it makes things even more complicated that the same device can (and will) run different versions of the OS.

Comment: This isn't the answer to the question. Devices, especially when dealing with lower level calls to things like cameras, can be very quirky. The knowing the prevalence of an API level doesn't help with this at all.

Answer (score 3):

You might have discovered [this](https://www.handsetdetection.com/categories/infographics) already, But I will still post it for the sake of those who might come across this thread in the future.

The website I linked above is [Handset Detection](https://www.handsetdetection.com/). As I was googling android popular device distribution, I often see blogs referencing Handset Detection, so I visited it and it showed some android device statistics per country.

Here is the link to the blog of the website:

> http://www.handsetdetection.com/blog/

For specific infographics, you can check this out:

> https://www.handsetdetection.com/categories/infographics

For the specific link that I was referring to in this answer when I posted it, you can check this out:

> https://www.handsetdetection.com/blog/android-statistics-breaking-down-droid-use-in-the-developing-world-infographic

Comment: Those seem to be OS version stats, not device stats.

Comment: @OhadSchneider Thanks for the notif. The link I provided above is a general link to the blog, so I can understand your confusion. I tried searching for the specific blog post I was referring to years ago, and I edited the answer to refer to this link. I also updated my answer with the specific link to the infographics. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @OhadSchneider Thanks :) It really is outdated. I just put it there because that was what I was referring to when I posted this answer. Looking at the `infographics` blog posts, I can see that that website no longer does worldwide device infographics. Kind of unfortunate because their infographics were fun to look at. Anyway, the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9910451/2431281) by @Chad seems to have the latest(?) device statistics. I humbly refer you to his answer. :)
Oh and thanks for noticing my answer. At just 2 upvotes I thought it would go unnoticed. :D

Comment: ...And then I read the comment below that top answer, and the website seems to be showing only the distribution for Samsung Android Devices haha.

Answer (score 1):

Found a pretty useful resource: https://deviceatlas.com/blog/most-popular-android-smartphones .
It shows most used Android devices based on the country. Rankings are based on the traffic share. Current report is based on the Q4 2018 data.

Other than that you can also find the usage of specific device in countries all over world.
https://deviceatlas.com/device-data/explorer/webusage/traffic/no-tablet/country/us?search=Samsung%20Galaxy%20S9